# Arraylist data empties automatically

Tags: android, api, arraylist, retrofit

I am receiveing data from an API and adding the response to an arrayList (hero_list)...as you can see that the request is made successfully in the first picture and the size of the arrayList is 117 (that's all the data).

[image]

But after exiting the call function the arrayList becomes empty

[image]

Comment: Please give some code

Comment: post the call function

Comment: sounds like problem with the scopes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is happening because of multithreading. You are not getting data on the main thread. While you are getting size on the main thread. Your main thread run before the onResponse. In order to correct it make the hero_list.size wait or ren it in onResponse.

Answer (score 0):

That's because `call2.execute()` is an [Asynchronous](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Asynchronous_method_invocation) method.

What's happening is you are calling `execute` and then the program immediately moves to the next line which is `hero_list.size();`. Later on Retrofit returns a result to the callback `onResponse()` and then you can use the result.

Answer (score 0):

Try to create an ArrayList inside that Asynchronous method, then .postValue that ArrayList to the ArrayList outside the AsyncTask.

Answer (score 0):

**Option 1:**

> You call hero_list.size() before getting response.Check size in on
>   response method and update Ui after

`if(hero_list.size() != 0){
//Update Ui.
}`

**Option 2:**

> Use interface in onResponse method.